# Конкурентоспособность

Tags: грамотная-речь

Зависла вчера над предложением со словом "конкурентоспособный". Никак не могла понять, как оно сочетается с другими словами. Нужно было сформулировать фразу о том, что некий товар становиться конкурентоспособный в сравнении с другим товаром. Но вообще правильно ли сказать: "конкурентоспособен по сравнению с..."?
Заранее благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По определению, "конкурентоспособность товара — это способность продукции быть более привлекательной для потребителя (покупателя) по сравнению с другими изделиями аналогичного вида и назначения, благодаря лучшему соответствию своих качественных и стоимостных характеристик требованиям данного рынка и потребительским оценкам»

Когда мы говорим, что товар СТАНОВИТСЯ КОНКУРЕНТОСПОСОБНЫМ, мы считаем, что он вошел в группу таких товаров, но в этом случае речь не идет о сравнении.

В то же время внутри этой группы товары обладают большей или меньшей конкурентоспособностью. Соответственно, можно сказать, что  товар становится БОЛЕЕ конкурентоспособным в сравнении с другими товарами.